# esp32 arduino ide Web Socket stream json no errors but no values

Tags: json, websocket, deserialization, streaming, esp32

Thank you for considering this problem.

I'm streaming a small json from a Web socket and can see the stringified json arrive to the client because it prints to the serial monitor, but then it deserializes to a 1 or 0 instead of my key:value pairs. I just want it to parse the json so that the rest of my program can use the values. I get no errors. Tried both Dynamic and Static json docs. Tried triple the memory requirement.

Arduino:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#define ARDUINOJSON_ENABLE_ARDUINO_STREAM 1
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <StreamUtils.h>

const char* ssid = "ssid";
const char* password = "pw";

const char* host = "10.0.0.250";

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);

  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network


int loopCount = 0;

StaticJsonDocument<384> doc;
DeserializationError error;

void loop()
{
  //delay(5000);
  ++loopCount;
  if (loopCount > 1) return;

  Serial.print("connecting to ");
  Serial.println(host);

  // Use WiFiClient class to create TCP connections
  WiFiClient client;
  const int httpPort = 1337;
  if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) {
    Serial.println("connection failed");
    return;
  }

  // This will send the request to the server
  client.print(String("GET ") + "HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
             "Host: " + host + "\r\n" +
             "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
  unsigned long timeout = millis();
  while (client.available() == 0) {
    if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
      Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
      client.stop();
      return;
    }
  }
  // Read all the lines of the reply from server and print them to Serial
  while (client.available() > 0) {
    ReadLoggingStream loggingClient(client, Serial);
    error = deserializeJson(doc, loggingClient);
  }
  Serial.println("");
  
  if (error) {
    Serial.print(F("deserializeJson() failed: "));
    Serial.println(error.f_str());
    return;
  } 

//this doesn't work
int id = doc["id"]; // Should be 5 but I get 0 for every value
Serial.print("id: "); Serial.println(id);
}

/*Serial monitor:
14:21:25.905 -> 
07:16:36.574 -> WiFi connected
07:16:36.574 -> IP address: 
07:16:36.574 -> 10.0.0.113
07:16:36.574 -> connecting to 10.0.0.250
07:16:36.849 -> "{\"id\":5,\"nom\":\"whynot\",\"delayStart\":200,\"rampePWM\":11,\"pulseWelding\":200,\"speedBalayage\":0.4,\"speedWelding\":0.5,\"speedWire\":1.1,\"balayage\":0.8,\"pulseWire\":5,\"retractWire\":7}"
07:16:36.849 -> id: 0
*/
```

The tcp-socket is in my node express setup. The file projet.json is only the json seen above ^^ no white space.

```
var net = require('net');
var serverN = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    fs.readFile("./data/projet.json", 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        socket.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        socket.pipe(socket);
    });
});

serverN.listen(1337, '10.0.0.250');
```

Comment: Just tried the deserialize Message Pack, same result https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/msgpack/deserializemsgpack/

Answer (score 0):

I can only show you how i use it to get the right values. i use a DynamicJsonDocument in my solution:

```
 DynamicJsonDocument root(2048);
 DeserializationError err = deserializeJson(root, http.getString());
 String TravelTimes = root["travelTime"];
```

Otherwise you can also try to output the values directly via the jsonobject

```
JsonObject object = doc.to<JsonObject>();
const char* id = object["id"];
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I get the same result with a DynamicJsonDocument. I'm trying to avoid httpclient as it's more than I need. When I convert doc to a JsonObject the result is a 1 or 0, it's not json-formatted key-value pairs as displayed in the Serial Monitor. I just wish it would display the error..

Answer (score 0):

The code parses the JSON string but then calls `JsonDocument::to<T>()` to obtain a JsonObject. This method clears the document - from https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsondocument/to/

> Clears the JsonDocument and converts it to the specified type.

`JsonDocument::as<T>()` should be used instead:

```
 JsonObject object = doc.as<JsonObject>();
```

From https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/jsondocument/as/

> Casts JsonDocument to the specified type.
>
> Unlike JsonDocument::to(), this function doesn’t change the content of the JsonDocument.

You can also use [`serializeJsonPretty()`](https://arduinojson.org/v6/api/json/serializejsonpretty/) to display the JsonObject on the serial output. Instead of:

```
JsonObject object = doc.to<JsonObject>();
Serial.println(object);
```

this can be done with:

```
serializeJsonPretty(doc, Serial);
```

Comment: Serial.print(doc) doesn't compile. The error is /* fetch valuesnote: candidate: size_t Print::print(const __FlashStringHelper*) size_t print(const __FlashStringHelper *); ...so I tried both .as<> and .to<> JsonObject to see what I was expecting doc to contain. I get either 1 or 0 when I do this. I'll update my question, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you need to print the JSON object to the serial output then use serializeJsonPretty. I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: All I want is for the wifi client to receive the json from the socket and parse it so that I can access the values in the rest of my program. The json appears in the Serial monitor, so it's arriving at the client, but doc = 1 or 0 instead of my key:value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to bblanchon of ArduinoJson - The node socket was stringifying the json twice. I changed the socket to socket.write(data) instead of socket.write(JSON.stringify(data)) and it works.

See full explanation here
https://github.com/bblanchon/ArduinoJson/issues/1507

Thanks again!